# Fast lossless image compression in Android?

Tags: java, android, graphics, mobile

I need to save a series of large bitmaps to disk in Android in a lossless format. However, I've found that the built-in PNG encoder is quite slow e.g. it's taking about 8 seconds to save 3 large images when I need something that takes around 2 seconds. Are there any other lossless options for saving bitmaps in Android?

I'm happy to sacrifice a little disk space for speed. However, the compression level parameter for saving PNG images in Android is ignored for PNGs (by design). Perhaps there are some easy to use options that involve the NDK?

Comment: How large is large? I think 2.5 seconds per image is pretty okay-ish for a mobile device.

Comment: @Reno: Roughly five 800x600 images which is about 10Mb of raw data. I'd expect the raw data could be written in under 2 seconds but the size of this is too big. About 8 seconds for the PNG is too long but the compression is much better. I'm looking if there's anything in-between these two options. I'm thinking RLE/packbits compression alone might be OK but there's no built-in way of doing this. I've tried using Deflate (which is part of Java) but this is quite slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slowness may depend on how (the approach) you are saving it..Did you try using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?

Comment: The image saving happens within a call to new Thread(...).start(). While saving is happening I show a ProgressDialog. AsyncTasks are low priority so I would have thought AsyncTask would be slower.